# Number of possible combinations of letters in word given first 2 letters have to be the same

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $3$ distinct characters, $a, b, c$. I have to make a word of $6$ characters using each of these $3$ twice, for example, '$abcabc$'. The number of possible combinations for this is $6!$ ($6$ choices for first character, $5$ for the second and so on).

Now, I want to get the possible combinations such that the first two character are the same. Is it correct to say that the possible combinations for this is $2 * 1 * 4!$ ?

So, for n distinct characters, the number of possible combinations would be $n * 1 * (2n-2)!$. Being rusty in Combinatorics, I am being unable to judge if I am correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why should there be $6!$ ways without any restrictions..you have 3 letters andthat each of them is repeated twice .So first of all you will $6!/(2!×2!×2)$ combiations..and for your questions it shoud be $3×4!/(2!×2!)$ ways

Comment: I understand my mistake. Thanks for the answer.